# How to detect Puppet agent failure "Could not retrieve catalog from remote server" on the agent machine

Tags: puppet

I'm wanting to detect errors of the sort "Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Evaluation Error:..." on the local machine running the agent. I would have thought `/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/state/last_run_summary.yaml` would be the place to look but nothing in there indicates there's a problem:

```yaml
---
version:
  config: 5ff9a6e08b2aa8c71373a2218463d2bd2a1b8e7d
  puppet: 6.15.0
resources:
  changed: 0
  corrective_change: 0
  failed: 0
  failed_to_restart: 0
  out_of_sync: 0
  restarted: 0
  scheduled: 0
  skipped: 0
  total: 527
time:
  anchor: 0.000736024
  apt_key: 0.002215042
  archive: 0.0008249469999999999
  augeas: 0.5257871009999999
  catalog_application: 9.45769479504088
  config_retrieval: 0.060096837987657636
  convert_catalog: 0.7368292089668103
  debconf: 0.186004635
  exec: 0.7356288650000001
  fact_generation: 5.458149918005802
  # ...snip...
  last_run: 1593647340
changes:
  total: 0
events:
  failure: 0
  success: 0
  total: 0
```

`last_run` matches the time of the last failure (so it's not old), but there are 0 `failure` events. It also seems strange that it could not retrieve the catalog yet it knows the number of resources and they have entries under `time` – I'm presuming that's copied from the last run where it could retrieve a catalog.

How on the local machine can I detect this without looking for magic strings in journalctl?

Comment: Do you have the `use_cache_on_failure` configuration option turned on on the agent?  It seems plausible that that would cause the catalog retrieval failure to be masked, and *highly* plausible that it would account for the last run log having timing and resource-count details.

Comment: @JohnBollinger. I don't explicitly, but `usecacheonfailure` is `true` by default (and [recommended](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/config_important_settings.html)). I guess I could disable it and detect nothing happened but still seems strange there is no other way to no the agent is not receiving changes.

Comment: The agent does not "receive changes" under any circumstances, and perhaps thinking that it does is contributing to your discomfort.  The agent receives a catalog of configuration properties from the master, and for most sites this changes only rarely.  The fact that it changes rarely is the main factor in favor of ever falling back to a cached catalog.  Testing new configurations and troubleshooting failures are two major use cases for turning it off, but not everyone agrees with Puppet, Inc. that it is wise to have it enabled ever.

Comment: Found this existing (and abandoned) Puppet issue of exactly this: https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-2089?jql=project%20%3D%20PUP%20AND%20text%20~%20%22summary%20last%20run%20catalog%20retrieve%22